# FindViewById cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, android

I am trying to access a method, that changes a text field in the UI, of an Activity from another Java file. 
In Game.java (normal Java file in the background) I have some static variables that get changed over time. I want the changes in these variables to be reflected in the actual UI. Hence, I am trying to access the method "changeName" in DisplayMessageActivity.java which would reflect the corresponding changes (display_message_activity.xml).

This is the method in DisplayMessageActivity.java that I am trying to call from Game.java

```
public void changeName() {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.petname);
    text.setText("" + Game.name);
}
```

To call `DisplayMessageActivity.changeName()` from Game.java, I have to change it to a static method.

```
public static void changeName() {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.petname);
    text.setText("" + Game.name);
}
```

But doing that gives me an error "non-static method cannot be accessed from static context" for "findViewByID". 
I even tried making an instance of DisplayMessageActivity.java in Game.java to access the "changeName" method without making it static. However that throws a nullPointerException at `TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.petname);`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are the static variables necessary? Could you put them in a POJO and initialize them in a constructor?

Comment: Yeah the static variables are necessary. I don't want to make instances of Game.java because I have to access the same variables from different Activities

Comment: You could use the [Singleton design pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html), this ensures there is only a single instance of the class across all activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a static reference to `DisplayMessageActivity` in itself and initialize it in the `onCreate()`.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity {
DisplayMessageActivity instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ...
        instance = this;
        ...
    }

}
```

Then from Game.java you can access the non-static method using:

```
DisplayMessageActivity.instance.changeName();
```

**EDIT:** Btw, your NPE is being thrown because you created a new instance of DisplayMessageActivity which is not the one you are actually using.